# VueJS: Disable Select List Items that already are used

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning Vue.js and so I try to build a little list which assigns the countrycode to the taxes in the specific countries (I know - boring stuff, but it's "translatable" to my work later, I hope).

This is how I generate the select list:

```
<select class="uk-form-small" v-model="newTax.countrycode">
    <option v-for="country in countries" value="{{ $key }}">{{country}}</option>                        
</select>
```

Then I created a form to add items:

```
<form class="uk-width-large-2-3" @submit="add">
    <div class = "uk-form-label">
    <select class="uk-form-small" v-model="newTax.countrycode">
        <option v-for="country in countries" value="{{ $key }}">{{country}}</option>                        
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class = "uk-form-controls uk-form-controls-text">
    <input class="uk-input-large uk-width-1-4" type = "number" placeholder="{{ 'vat' | trans }}" v-model="newTax.vat" number>
    <input class="uk-input-large uk-width-1-4" type = "number" placeholder="{{ 'reducedvat' | trans }}" v-model="newTax.reducedvat" number>
    <button class="uk-button" @click="add">{{ 'Add' | trans }}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The items are displayed this way:

```
<div class = "uk-form-row" v-for="vat in config.vats"> 
    <span class = "uk-form-label">{{vat.countrycode}}</span>
    <div class = "uk-form-controls uk-form-controls-text">
        <p class = "uk-form-controls-condensed">
            <span class="uk-align-right">
                <button @click="remove(vat)" class="uk-button uk-button-danger"><i class="uk-icon-remove"></i></button>
            </span>                     

            <label class="uk-form-label">{{ 'VAT' | trans }}</label>
             <div class="uk-form-controls">
                <input class="uk-form-small uk-form-width-mini" type="number" v-model="vat.vat" number> {{ 'percent' | trans }}                          </div>
            <label class="uk-form-label">{{ 'Reduced VAT' | trans }}</label>
             <div class="uk-form-controls">
                <input class="uk-form-small uk-form-width-mini" type="number" v-model="vat.reducedvat" number>  {{ 'percent' | trans }}                          </div>
         </div>                                                                      
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine, too.

The items are storable and removable - everything is fine.

**But:** I would like to grey out items that are already defined. How could I do that?

My first attempt does not work:

```
<option v-for = "country in countries" value = "{{ $key }}" :disabled="config.vats.includes($key)">{{country}}</option>
```

It throws no JS-error but all options are available and enabled.

**Arrays and objects as a dump:**

The content of countries is:

```
{ "AF": "Afghanistan", "AL": "Albania", "DZ": "Algeria", "AS": "American Samoa", "AD": "Andorra", "AO": "Angola", "AI": "Anguilla", "AQ": "Antarctica", "AG": "Antigua and Barbuda", "AR": "Argentina", "AM": "Armenia", "AW": "Aruba", "AU": "Australia", "AT": "Austria", "AZ": "Azerbaijan", "BS": "Bahamas", "BH": "Bahrain", "BD": "Bangladesh", "BB": "Barbados", "BY": "Belarus", "BE": "Belgium", "BZ": "Belize", "BJ": "Benin", "BM": "Bermuda", "BT": "Bhutan", "BO": "Bolivia", "BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "BW": "Botswana", "BV": "Bouvet Island", "BR": "Brazil", "BQ": "British Antarctic Territory", "IO": "British Indian Ocean Territory", "VG": "British Virgin Islands", "BN": "Brunei", "BG": "Bulgaria", "BF": "Burkina Faso", "BI": "Burundi", "KH": "Cambodia", "CM": "Cameroon", "CA": "Canada", "CT": "Canton and Enderbury Islands", "CV": "Cape Verde", "KY": "Cayman Islands", "CF": "Central African Republic", "TD": "Chad", "CL": "Chile", "CN": "China", "CX": "Christmas Island", "CC": "Cocos [Keeling] Islands", "CO": "Colombia", "KM": "Comoros", "CG": "Congo - Brazzaville", "CD": "Congo - Kinshasa", "CK": "Cook Islands", "CR": "Costa Rica", "HR": "Croatia", "CU": "Cuba", "CY": "Cyprus", "CZ": "Czech Republic", "CI": "Côte d’Ivoire", "DK": "Denmark", "DJ": "Djibouti", "DM": "Dominica", "DO": "Dominican Republic", "NQ": "Dronning Maud Land", "DD": "East Germany", "EC": "Ecuador", "EG": "Egypt", "SV": "El Salvador", "GQ": "Equatorial Guinea", "ER": "Eritrea", "EE": "Estonia", "ET": "Ethiopia", "FK": "Falkland Islands", "FO": "Faroe Islands", "FJ": "Fiji", "FI": "Finland", "FR": "France", "GF": "French Guiana", "PF": "French Polynesia", "TF": "French Southern Territories", "FQ": "French Southern and Antarctic Territories", "GA": "Gabon", "GM": "Gambia", "GE": "Georgia", "DE": "Germany", "GH": "Ghana", "GI": "Gibraltar", "GR": "Greece", "GL": "Greenland", "GD": "Grenada", "GP": "Guadeloupe", "GU": "Guam", "GT": "Guatemala", "GG": "Guernsey", "GN": "Guinea", "GW": "Guinea-Bissau", "GY": "Guyana", "HT": "Haiti", "HM": "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "HN": "Honduras", "HK": "Hong Kong SAR China", "HU": "Hungary", "IS": "Iceland", "IN": "India", "ID": "Indonesia", "IR": "Iran", "IQ": "Iraq", "IE": "Ireland", "IM": "Isle of Man", "IL": "Israel", "IT": "Italy", "JM": "Jamaica", "JP": "Japan", "JE": "Jersey", "JT": "Johnston Island", "JO": "Jordan", "KZ": "Kazakhstan", "KE": "Kenya", "KI": "Kiribati", "KW": "Kuwait", "KG": "Kyrgyzstan", "LA": "Laos", "LV": "Latvia", "LB": "Lebanon", "LS": "Lesotho", "LR": "Liberia", "LY": "Libya", "LI": "Liechtenstein", "LT": "Lithuania", "LU": "Luxembourg", "MO": "Macau SAR China", "MK": "Macedonia", "MG": "Madagascar", "MW": "Malawi", "MY": "Malaysia", "MV": "Maldives", "ML": "Mali", "MT": "Malta", "MH": "Marshall Islands", "MQ": "Martinique", "MR": "Mauritania", "MU": "Mauritius", "YT": "Mayotte", "FX": "Metropolitan France", "MX": "Mexico", "FM": "Micronesia", "MI": "Midway Islands", "MD": "Moldova", "MC": "Monaco", "MN": "Mongolia", "ME": "Montenegro", "MS": "Montserrat", "MA": "Morocco", "MZ": "Mozambique", "MM": "Myanmar [Burma]", "NA": "Namibia", "NR": "Nauru", "NP": "Nepal", "NL": "Netherlands", "AN": "Netherlands Antilles", "NT": "Neutral Zone", "NC": "New Caledonia", "NZ": "New Zealand", "NI": "Nicaragua", "NE": "Niger", "NG": "Nigeria", "NU": "Niue", "NF": "Norfolk Island", "KP": "North Korea", "VD": "North Vietnam", "MP": "Northern Mariana Islands", "NO": "Norway", "OM": "Oman", "PC": "Pacific Islands Trust Territory", "PK": "Pakistan", "PW": "Palau", "PS": "Palestinian Territories", "PA": "Panama", "PZ": "Panama Canal Zone", "PG": "Papua New Guinea", "PY": "Paraguay", "YD": "People's Democratic Republic of Yemen", "PE": "Peru", "PH": "Philippines", "PN": "Pitcairn Islands", "PL": "Poland", "PT": "Portugal", "PR": "Puerto Rico", "QA": "Qatar", "RO": "Romania", "RU": "Russia", "RW": "Rwanda", "RE": "Réunion", "BL": "Saint Barthélemy", "SH": "Saint Helena", "KN": "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "LC": "Saint Lucia", "MF": "Saint Martin", "PM": "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "VC": "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "WS": "Samoa", "SM": "San Marino", "SA": "Saudi Arabia", "SN": "Senegal", "RS": "Serbia", "CS": "Serbia and Montenegro", "SC": "Seychelles", "SL": "Sierra Leone", "SG": "Singapore", "SK": "Slovakia", "SI": "Slovenia", "SB": "Solomon Islands", "SO": "Somalia", "ZA": "South Africa", "GS": "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "KR": "South Korea", "ES": "Spain", "LK": "Sri Lanka", "SD": "Sudan", "SR": "Suriname", "SJ": "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "SZ": "Swaziland", "SE": "Sweden", "CH": "Switzerland", "SY": "Syria", "ST": "São Tomé and Príncipe", "TW": "Taiwan", "TJ": "Tajikistan", "TZ": "Tanzania", "TH": "Thailand", "TL": "Timor-Leste", "TG": "Togo", "TK": "Tokelau", "TO": "Tonga", "TT": "Trinidad and Tobago", "TN": "Tunisia", "TR": "Turkey", "TM": "Turkmenistan", "TC": "Turks and Caicos Islands", "TV": "Tuvalu", "UM": "U.S. Minor Outlying Islands", "PU": "U.S. Miscellaneous Pacific Islands", "VI": "U.S. Virgin Islands", "UG": "Uganda", "UA": "Ukraine", "SU": "Union of Soviet Socialist Republics", "AE": "United Arab Emirates", "GB": "United Kingdom", "US": "United States", "ZZ": "Unknown or Invalid Region", "UY": "Uruguay", "UZ": "Uzbekistan", "VU": "Vanuatu", "VA": "Vatican City", "VE": "Venezuela", "VN": "Vietnam", "WK": "Wake Island", "WF": "Wallis and Futuna", "EH": "Western Sahara", "YE": "Yemen", "ZM": "Zambia", "ZW": "Zimbabwe", "AX": "Åland Islands" }
```

The config.vats contains of different arrays:

```
[ { "countrycode": "DE", "vat": 19, "reducedvat": 7 }, { "countrycode": "AL", "vat": 5, "reducedvat": 5 } ]
```

Now `{{config.vats.includes('DE') | json}}` returns `false` - I guess it's looking for an array-element with value DE which obviously does not exist.

Comment: Could you post your `countries` property value? We use `$key` to iterate through the properties of an Object, but sounds like `countries` would be an Array, in your example.

Comment: Hi @crabbly - thanks for your reply. I added the content of `countries` and `config.vats`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript `.includes()` will search a string within another string, but `config.vats` is an array.

First create a method to check if the `$key` is available in any of the `config.vats` array's objects `countrycode` property:

```
method: {
   vatMatch: function(code) {
      return this.config.vats.filter(function(vat) {
         return  vat.countrycode == code;
      }).length > 0;
   },
}
```

Then use it in your HTML:

```
<option v-for = "country in countries" value = "{{ $key }}"
        :disabled="vatMatch($key)">{{country}}
</option>
```